# Logic apps convert a particular key from JSON object array to delimited string

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Here is my JSON object array:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "b3cbd395-dfba-4d36-b6e5-161bf00c26a1",
            "businessPhones": [],
            "displayName": "Joe Bloggs",
            "givenName": null,
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": "joebloggs@domain.com",
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": null,
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": null,
            "userPrincipalName": "joebloggs_domain.com#EXT#@domain2.onmicrosoft.com"
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "b0b80e63-5be2-44c9-87b7-e6ec52432796",
            "businessPhones": [],
            "displayName": "John Doe",
            "givenName": "John",
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": "johndoe@domain.com",
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": null,
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": "Doe",
            "userPrincipalName": "johndoe_domain.com#EXT#@domain2.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to extract the `mail` key of each array object into a string like below so that I can then send an email to them later.
`joebloggs@domain.com;johndoe@domain.com`

I tried `join(body('Parse_JSON_owners')?['value']?['mail'], ';')` but that gives error:

> The template language expression 'join(body('Parse_JSON_owners')?['value']?['mail'], ';')' cannot be evaluated because property 'mail' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index.

Comment: Loop over the array and concatenate each value into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialise a string variable and use `Append to string variable` inside a For-each loop.

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to avoid using variable inside the loop, but I guess there is no workaround!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Select Data operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations?tabs=consumption#select-action)

[image: Select Data Operation]

With this Action you can map your objects to a new array of objects.
Select your source object, in your case that would be `body('Parse_JSON_owners')`
In order to only get an array with value types, you can first click on the switch button at the right side of the action.

[image: Switch button]

Add your property, in your case that would be `item()?['value']?['mail']`.

[image: Add the property]
[image: Result after saving]

**Result output**
In a run this would result in an array with plain string values.

[image: Result output]

After this, you can join the array the way you already had in mind, with the join function. This would look something like this: `join(body('Select'), ';')`